# Django template tags get/filter models

Tags: django, templatetags

I'm trying to accomplish something using template tags.
I have a shop which have ratings of products. I wanted a template tag that get rating value and user if exists.

```
@register.simple_tag
def puntaje_usuario(prod):
    rating = Rating.objects.get(usuario=request.user.id, producto=prod.id)
    return rating
```

I wanna use it here: (template rating stars)

```
<div class="prod-info">
<h5><a href="{{x.get_absolute_url_shop}}" class="txt-muted"> {{x.nombre}} </a></h5>
{% if puntaje_usuario x %}
    <!-- SAME SELECT THAT "else" WITH RATING VALUE OPTION SELECTED -->
{% else %}
<div class="stars stars-example-css m-b-10">
    <select class="rating-star puntaje-producto" data-url="{% url 'puntuar_producto' %}" data-producto="{{x.id}}" data-usuario="{{request.user.id}}" name="rating" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<h6 class="txt-info">{% rating_promedio x.id %}</h6>
{% endif %}
```

The error I'm getting is **Unused ''x'' at end of if expression.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a tag directly in an if like that. You need to assign it to a variable first:

```
{% puntaje_usuario x as my_val %}
{% if my_val %}
    ...
```